# Which java development tool to download for windows7 x64?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-me

I want to use eclipse for a java coding and compiling for my home use. So, which version should i download as i don't have any of the previous versions or plugin installed on my system (i.e. Win 7 ultimate, x64)?

Comment: The latest stable version is always a good start.

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer**

Get [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers for Windows x64](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/indigo/SR1/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR1-win32-x86_64.zip).

**The long answer**

You may download Eclipse from the http://eclipse.org website.
The last stable version of Eclipse is 3.7.1, codename Indigo. The next should be relased in June 2012.

You may compare what is inside the various offered package in the following page:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php

There are two main packages for Java, if you need it just to learn the language (or if you know you don't need Java EE), the smaller could do, but if you wish to do Java EE development, you need to larger.

[Eclipse IDE for Java Developers for Windows x64](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/indigo/SR1/eclipse-java-indigo-SR1-win32-x86_64.zip)

[Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers for Windows x64](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/indigo/SR1/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR1-win32-x86_64.zip)

Answer (score 0):

I use Eclipse 64x and Java 64x.

-> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
-> http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

In this web http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/, choose "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" or "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers".

Regards!.

Comment: what is the difference between java EE and classic version?

Comment: Java EE (Enterprise Edition) is ready to develop more types of applications, especially Web-oriented.